# How to swipe between activities like in Instagram

Tags: android, xml, instagram, transition, swipe-gesture

you can see the example here

[first activity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ns2T9.jpg)[2nd activity:transition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YtE5m.jpg)

Comment: the 2nd image not exist or available can you reupload it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a ViewPager you can check this out from android Doc

For refrence:
https://developer.android.com/training/animation/screen-slide